# Uploading Files and Images with mkdir specific location

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

What I am trying to put images where my folder is generate from "$tablename", but fail to bring the image there. How do I store the uploaded files ?

I like to upload images from my form.

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="files" multiple />
```

No matter which of those upload techniques I use is not good to use, to save the file to a specific location on the server.

If you have an idea how to do this problem please.

here is the mkdir code. The code is works fine.

```
 <?php
$tablename = "fisa";
$next_increment = 0;
$qShowStatus = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '$tablename'";
$qShowStatusResult = mysql_query($qShowStatus) or die("" . mysql_error() . "" . $qShowStatus);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qShowStatusResult);
$next_increment = $row['Auto_increment'];

echo "$next_increment";

$tablename = (string) ("$next_increment");

$year = date("Y");
$month = date("m");
$day = date("d");
If (!file_exists($year)) {
    $createsyear = mkdir("$year", 0777);
} else {
    If (!file_exists("$year/$month")) {
        $createsmonth = mkdir("$year/$month", 0777);
    } else {
        If (!file_exists("$year/$month/$day")) {
            $createsday = mkdir("$year/$month/$day", 0777);
        } else {
            If (!file_exists($year / $month / $day / $tablename)) {
                $createsday = mkdir("$year/$month/$day/$tablename", 0777);
            } else {
                //dada
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thank You.

Comment: then why `java` tag ?

Comment: you should learn about `move_uploaded_file` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem

```
 <?php 
    $tablename      = "fisa";
    $next_increment     = 0;
    $qShowStatus        = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '$tablename'";
    $qShowStatusResult  = mysql_query($qShowStatus) or die ( "" . mysql_error() . "" . $qShowStatus );

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qShowStatusResult);
    $next_increment = $row['Auto_increment'];

    echo "$next_increment";

    $tablename = (string)("$next_increment");
    $year = date("Y");
    $month = date("m");
    $day = date("d");

    If(!file_exists($year)){
    $createsyear = mkdir("$year", 0777);
    }
    else
    {
    If(!file_exists("$year/$month")){
    $createsmonth = mkdir("$year/$month", 0777);
    }
    else
    {
    If(!file_exists("$year/$month/$day")){
    $createsday = mkdir("$year/$month/$day", 0777);
    }
    else
    {
    If(!file_exists($year/$month/$day/$tablename)){
    $createsday = mkdir("$year/$month/$day/$tablename/", 0777);



    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
    $max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb

    $target = "$year/$month/$day/$tablename/"; 
    $count = 0;

    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                continue; // Skip file if any error found
            }          
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
                if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                    $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                    continue; // Skip large files
                }
                elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                    $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                    continue; // Skip invalid file formats
                }
                else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $target.$name)) {
                        $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
    else
    {

    }
    }
    }


    }


    ?>
```

Comment: now appeared another problem, is generated a number like 450. want to take a -449 not to generate 450 one in minus. it is possible ? when I make  one file, it generates two files one 450 and 451 I do not want this. the ID take from my mysql tabel

Answer (score 1):

Here I give basic example for file upload.

in HTML

```
<form action="phpfilename.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="files" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

In PHP

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $path = $_FILES["files"]["name"];
    $target = "$year/$month/$day/$tablename/$path";  //this is your path where image need to be saved
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"],  $target);
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is PHP. Your code was PHP only. @razvan  `value = ??`  what do you mean??

Comment: <input type="file" id="file" name="files" multiple value="<?php  here ?>" />

Comment: the last action is  `If(!file_exists($year/$month/$day/$tablename)){
$createsday = mkdir("$year/$month/$day/$tablename", 0777);`

Comment: What do you need exactly.?

Comment: I like in the location **Ex: 2015\10\14\445** to be image, and how many times i generated last code to be able to upload image there from my input form

Comment: Your Codu is almost about what I need, but is is not good. Lok up on my code and se where generate teh last code, is from **tablename ** from my mysql tabel

Comment: now appeared another problem, is generated a number like 450. want to take a -449 not to generate 450 one in minus. it is possible ? when I give make one file, it generates two files one 450 and 451 I do not want this.  the ID take from my mysql tabel

Comment: @razvan : I can't understand your problem. What is 450?? Update the code in question.

Comment: ID from mysql tabel I generate 450 ID, and from my ID I need to upload image in folder